# Matching substring in pattern in Python

Tags: python, regex, string, pattern-matching

I'd like to get the substring s2 in this string pattern

```
 ('s1', 's2', 's3', 's4')
```

with s1, s2, s3 being any string (with variable length) and the commas, the blanks and the brackets are those specific chars.
I wonder: is there a pythonic, simply way to do it using regex matching or similar?

Comment: `ast.literal_eval(s)[1]`

Comment: Are single quotes escaped in `s1`, `s2`, ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regular expression as follows could be used:

```
import re

print re.findall("'(\w+)'", "('s1', 's2', 's3', 's4')")
```

Giving you a list of all of the entries as follows:

```
['s1', 's2', 's3', 's4']
```

So for s2:

```
print re.findall("'(\w+)'", "('s1', 's2', 's3', 's4')")[1]
```

As another alternative, the Python `csv` module could be used which deals quite well with various quoting scenarios:

```
import csv, StringIO

text = "('s1', 's2', 's3', 's4')"
print next(csv.reader(StringIO.StringIO(text.strip("()")), skipinitialspace=True, quotechar="'"))[1]
```

This first converts the text into a file type object which is needed using the csv reader.

Answer (score 1):

You may get the answer through `ast`

```
import ast
h = "('s1', 's2', 's3', 's4')"
print ast.literal_eval(h)[1]
```

or

Through splitting.

```
print h.split(', ')[1]
```

or

```
print h.split("', '")[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

straightforward with strip and split alltogether.

```
s="""('s1', 's2', 's3', 's4')"""
print s.split()[1].strip("',")
```

but regex is more clean:

```
import re
s="""('s1', 's2', 's3', 's4')"""
print re.findall("\w\d",s)[1]
```